# I am trying to retrieve information from a Sharepoint list when clicking an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint list with 3 columns: Image, Title, and Description. I am trying to retrieve the items via ajax. The images I can get successfully and the idea is that when I click on the images I retrieve the title and description for the clicked image. What I am getting in the console, after clicking the image,is the first title and first description on the list regardless of the images I click on. After clicking the image, the title and description must append to a div with the id of #captionContainer.

```
var buildMainCarousel = function (items) {
    var flickitySlider = $('#flickityCarousel');
    var carouselContent;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        carouselContent = '<div class="carousel-cell">' +
            '<img src=" ' + items[i].Image.Url.replace("http://bc-net", "") + '"" alt="">' +
            '</div>';
        console.log(carouselContent);
        flickitySlider.append(carouselContent);
    }

};

var buildCaptions = function (items) {
    var captionContainer = $('#captionContainer');

 $(".carousel-cell img").click(function() {
    var clickedThumb= $(this);
        var title = items[i].Title;
        var description = items[i].Description;
       console.log(title);
        console.log(description);

});

};
```

```
var url1 = "/FunZone/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('funZone')/items";
var handle_ajax = function (url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = data.d.results;
            console.log(items);

            buildMainCarousel(items);
            buildCarouselNav(items);
            buildCaptions(items);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("Error: " + data);
        }

    });

};

handle_ajax(url1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Bootstrap Image carousel and SharePoint REST API with jQuery Ajax to achieve it, the following example for your reference.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.carouselCaption {
  background-color: #fee601;
  padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 5px 6px 0px #000;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var listName="funZone";
    GetImagesFromLibrary(listName);
});
function GetImagesFromLibrary(listName){
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/items?$top=5&$orderby=Created desc";
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        method: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
                var cInnerHtml="";
                if(i==0){
                    $("#myCarousel .carousel-indicators").append('<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>');
                    cInnerHtml+='<div class="item active">';                                                            
                }else{                  
                    $("#myCarousel .carousel-indicators").append('<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'+i+'"></li>');
                    cInnerHtml+='<div class="item">';               
                }
                cInnerHtml+='<img src="'+item.Image.Url+'" alt="'+item.Title+'" style="width:100%;">';
                cInnerHtml+='<div class="carousel-caption" style="display:none;"><h3>'+item.Title+'</h3><p>'+item.Description+'</p></div></div>';
                $("#myCarousel .carousel-inner").append(cInnerHtml);                
            });
            $(".carousel-inner img").click(function(){
                $(".carouselCaption").html($(this).next().html());
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">        
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<section class="carouselCaption mb-1">   
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. Your example makes a lot of sense and it works perfectly. However, I was given the flickity design and I am in charge of develop the functionality. The idea is to do the same as you did when clicking the thumbnail and the title and description will append to the yellow box at the bottom. Here is the visual [CodePen] (https://codepen.io/angelogianopulos/pen/gOYVzGO)

Comment: Thanks for the code @ LZ_MSFT the images are stacked and the carousel doesn't work. The console doesn't give me any errors.